# Resetting state based upon choice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom component that allows for my dropdowns to be generated via the backend, however i need to somehow store the two dropdown values in state, currently i am setting contractType to a value of 10 to meet the conditions of my conditional below, however when selecting a second value which is not 10 state is not reset, how could i achieve a change between two separate state values?

my code

```
     const [contractType, setContractType] = useState(10);


        function handleChange(event) {
            setContractType(oldValues => ({
                ...oldValues,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
            }));
        }
```

my component below

```
      <Search
                                type="procurementType"
                                name="procurementType"
                                label="Procurement Type"
                                id="procurementTypeId"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                value={contractType}
                            />
```

finally my if statement relating to the decision

```
{contractType == 10 ? <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
                    <Table className={classes.table}>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow >
                                <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Internal Ref</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Organisation</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {localContracts.map(row => (
                                <TableRow className={classes.tableRow}>
                                    <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>{row.id}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{row.internalRef}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{row.title}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{row.organisationId}</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </div> : <Table className={classes.table}>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow >
                                <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Internal Ref</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Organisation</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {frameworkContracts.map(row => (
                                <TableRow className={classes.tableRow}>
                                    <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>{row.id}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{row.internalRef}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{row.title}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{row.organisationId}</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>}
```

Comment: you are setting an initial value of 10 and then on `handleChange` you are trying to destructure 10 which is not an object...did you notice that?

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ I thought this may have been the problem, any advice?

Comment: Implement a simple use case. If you just need to store multiple types/values of same thing how about a collection/list/array of object? instead of initializing with 10 make it like `[{contractType: 10}]` then when you add more it may become `setContractTypes([...contractTypes, {contractType: 20}])` or if you want to update then search through `contractTypes` for the item and update it then set the updated list in the state. note that `contractTypes` is the state key name here